# Can I use an SSD as Cache to a NAS?

Tags: raid, ssd, cache

There is a NAS with Raid 10 that holds resources.

At a time, around 24 machines try to access the same resource (3d rendering in a render farm).

Although the network is 1Gbps and NAS is fast, the speed is really reduced and there is a bottleneck phenomenon there.

I wonder if there is a hardware way to use an SSD as a Cache machine for a NAS (Raid 10).

Comment: Are you sure the 1Gbps network connection isn't the bottleneck?  If you've got more than 4 or so disks in that RAID 10, then they should be saturating the 1Gbps link.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing what kind of a NAS it is.

Comment: What OS are you using? What protocol are you using to access the NAS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are definitely solutions that can leverage SSD drives as read-cache for an active working set of data in a NAS solution. Are you using a hardware NAS appliance? If so, there probably isn't a good way to provide cache to your existing equipment. However, you could look into [NexentaStor](http://www.nexentastor.org) or any [ZFS-based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZFS) storage solution, as the [L2ARC cache feature](http://www.zfsbuild.com/2010/04/15/explanation-of-arc-and-l2arc/) supports what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is. That said - it is likely your (likely  cheap end user) NAS simply does not support that.

Adaptec enterprise RAID cards of the latest generation support that even with write cache (6805Q). ZFS file system supports level 2 caches.

Every higher level SAN supports significant caches and tiered storage.

Cheap end user level SAN? No ;)

Comment: High-rep users are being encouraged to add a hat to your Gravatar: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2394/its-santa-time